# React memo child component render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm having trouble rendering my comment components.

So I have a `listComment` component and it has 2 child component `CommentItem` and `CommentGroup`.

My `CommentGroup` component is like a dropdown where you can open and close it.

I tried to use React.memo() but it still rendering children thats already rendered

My problem is that every time I add a new comment it renders again the child components that's already rendered. So the comments that's already open the `CommentGroup` closes. And i use `redux` for state-management.

PS sorry for the bad english.

**Comment Data**

```
[{
body: "comment 1",
comment_counter: 0,
createdAt: "2020-06-14T13:42:38.465Z",
heart_counter: 0,
ownerId: "5edce08cabc7ab1860c7bdf4",
postId: "5ee3770495bfce029842bc68",
_id: "5ee6294eb7295a1c04b62374"
}, {
body: "comment 2",
comment_counter: 0,
createdAt: "2020-06-14T13:42:38.465Z",
heart_counter: 0,
ownerId: "5edce08cabc7ab1860c7bdf4",
postId: "5ee3770495bfce029842bc68",
_id: "5ee6294eb7295a1c04b62374"
}]
```

**ListComments.js**

```
const comments = useSelector(state => state.comment.comments)

return comments.map(comment => {
        return (
            <div key={comment._id}>
                <CommentItem comment={comment} type="post_comment" />
                <div className={classes.mLeft}>
                    <CommentGroup counter={comment.comment_counter} />
                </div>
            </div >
        )
    })
```

**CommentGroup.js**

```
const CommentGroup = React.memo((props) => {
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

const onOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true)
}

const onClose = () => {
    setOpen(false)
}

return (
    <div>
        <Button
            size="small"
            color="primary"
            startIcon={
                !open ? <ArrowDropDownOutlinedIcon /> : <ArrowDropUpOutlinedIcon />
            }
            onClick={
                !open ? () => onOpen() : () => onClose()
            }
        >
            {!open ? 'View' : 'Hide'} {1} Replies
        </Button>
        CommentGroupOpen: {open ? 'true' : 'false'}
    </div>
)
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
 console.log(prevProps) // not getting called
 if (prevProps.counter !== nextProps.counter) {
    return false
 }
 return true
})

export default CommentGroup
```

**CommentItem** is just a display component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely because that all the comments have the same comment._id which is used as the key. I made a similar example and it worked fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-framework-stk5g

Comment: My bad with my data comment example they each have `unique_id`.